# Return True or False if value in cell matches value in range of cells

Tags: excel, string, vba, match

I have the following code to see if any of the cells in the range: `("B9:B" & LastRowCarArea)` match the value of cell: `ThisCellinProjectList`. The value of this cell will always be a String, never numeric.

```
If Application.Match(ThisCellinProjectList, CheckSheet.Range("B9:B" & LastrowCarArea), 1) > 1 Then
```

I am getting a run time error when there are no cells in the lookup range that match the cell value in ThisCellinProjectList, but cannot work out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would just use a `countif` function in the vba and have a condition of `>0` to identify if the value is in the range.  As to why you are getting that specific error, I'm not sure.

Comment: That's normal behavior, you will get an error if a match can't be found which you can trap with error handling. As @ Jarom mentioned though a countif would be much simpler.

Comment: `Application.Match(ThisCellinProjectList, CheckSheet.Range("B9:B" & LastrowCarArea), 1)` returns an error and you cannot test whether an error is greater than 1

Comment: or you can `If Not iserror(Application.Match(ThisCellinProjectList, CheckSheet.Range("B9:B" & LastrowCarArea), 1)) Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `For Each...Next` statement to find `ThisCellinProjectList` in `Range("B9:B" & LastrowCarArea)`.

```
Dim ThisCellinProjectList As String
Dim LastrowCarArea As Long
Dim myRange As Range

ThisCellinProjectList = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value
LastrowCarArea = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:B" & LastrowCarArea)

For Each cell In myRange
    If cell = ThisCellinProjectList Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7") = "TRUE"
'            cell.Offset(0, 1) = "TRUE"
        End If
Next cell
```